# How can I get a list of documents that have one or more managed metadata terms?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, spservices

I have videos that are **"tagged"** with one or more terms from managed metadata. I want to get a list of documents in the Documents library whose tags match one or more of the video's tags. I am able to get the managed metadata for the video using `spservices` (ex. 64;#Campaign Videos) but can't figure out how to use that to get a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the CAML query. The below mentioned technet explain in details with example how to build query and get the value.

[Querying on Managed Metadata Field Values in SharePoint Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625182.aspx)

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how to manage a sub-select. I basically need to do this:

SELECT * FROM Documents t1 WHERE MMLookupField IN (SELECT MMLookupField FROM Documents t2 WHERE t2.ID  = X)

...or something along those lines. I only want to make one spservices call if at all possible.